# Has anyone made a barebones rococo relay chain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rococo, relay-chain, rococo-local

I am curious if anyone made a rococo relay chain using node-template? Similar to this (https://github.com/buraktabn/relay-chain) but using rococo instead of kusama.

Comment: I didn’t make rococo relay with node template but I made one by forking rococo and creating new chain spec, etc https://github.com/kabocha-network/relay-chain/tree/v0.9.18